# JS find all sequences in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Giving an array (fixed length) of objects with the following structures:

```
{type: 'A', value: 1}
```

or

```
{type: 'B', text: 'b'}
```

What is the easiest way to find all the sequences of objects of type 'A' and return their indices?

An example:
For the following array:

```
[
  {type: 'A', value: 1}, {type: 'A', value: 2}, {type: 'B', text: 'b1'},
  {type: 'A', value: 11}, {type: 'A', value: 12}, {type: 'A', value: 13},
  {type: 'B', text: 'b2'}, {type: 'A', value: 10}, {type: 'B', text: 'b3'}
]
```

The output should be the following array:

```
[
  {startIndex: 0, startValue: 1, length: 2},
  {startIndex: 3, startValue: 11, length: 3},
  {startIndex: 7, startValue: 10, length: 1},
]
```

I guess the naive implementation would be to iterate with `forEach` and have many complex conditions but is there a simpler technique?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this. Add a variable `prev` to keep track of what the previous `type` was. If the current `type` is the type you are looking for: Add an object if the previous item had a different `type`. Else, just increment the `length` property

```js
let input = [{type:'A',value:1},{type:'A',value:2},{type:'B',text:'b1'},{type:'A',value:11},{type:'A',value:12},{type:'A',value:13},{type:'B',text:'b2'},{type:'A',value:10},{type:'B',text:'b3'}],
    prev;

const output = input.reduce((acc, { type, value }, i) => {
  if (type === 'A') {
    if (prev !== type) {
      acc.push({ startIndex: i, startValue: value, length: 1 })
    } else {
      acc[acc.length - 1].length++
    }
  }

  prev = type
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array and chweck the value and the type for creating a new group.

```js
var array = [{ type: 'A', value: 1 }, { type: 'A', value: 2 }, { type: 'B', text: 'b1' }, { type: 'A', value: 11 }, { type: 'A', value: 12 }, { type: 'A', value: 13 }, { type: 'B', text: 'b2' }, { type: 'A', value: 10 }, { type: 'B', text: 'b3' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { type, value }, i, a) => {
        var previous = a[i - 1] || {},
            last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (!isFinite(value) || type !== 'A') return r;
        if (previous.type !== type) {
            r.push({ startIndex: i, startValue: value, length: 1 });
            return r;
        }
        if (value === a[last.startIndex].value + last.length) last.length++;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `forEach` loop. its simple to read and doesnt complicate your code.

```js
let arr = [
  {type: 'A', value: 1}, {type: 'A', value: 2}, {type: 'B', text: 'b1'},
  {type: 'A', value: 11}, {type: 'A', value: 12}, {type: 'A', value: 13},
  {type: 'B', text: 'b2'}, {type: 'A', value: 10}, {type: 'B', text: 'b3'}
]

function findSequences(arr, character) {
  let seq = []

  let seqStarted = false;
  let seqI = 0;

  arr.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (el.type == character) {
      if (seqStarted == true) {
        seq[seqI].length += 1;
      } else {
        seqStarted = true;
        seq.push({
          startIndex: i,
          startValue: el.value,
          length: 1
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (seqStarted) {
        seqStarted = false;
        seqI++;
      }
    }
  })

  return seq;
}

console.log(findSequences(arr, 'A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can get any simpler that just iterating over the array using a `for` loop and constructing your desired answer. Also, this solution has linear complexity, as you're traversing the array just once. Not sure why you'd need "many complex conditions" though.

Something like this seems pretty OK to me:

```js
const arr = [
  {type: 'A', value: 1}, {type: 'A', value: 2}, {type: 'B', text: 'b1'},
  {type: 'A', value: 11}, {type: 'A', value: 12}, {type: 'A', value: 13},
  {type: 'B', text: 'b2'}, {type: 'A', value: 10}, {type: 'B', text: 'b3'}
];

const result = [];

for (let [index, el] of arr.entries()) {
  if (el.type === 'A') {
    // account for the first entry found
    if (result.length === 0) {
      result.push({startIndex: index, length: 1, startValue: el.value});
    } else {
      const lastSequence = result[result.length - 1];
      // check if the we are in a sequence
      if (lastSequence.startIndex + lastSequence.length === index) {
        lastSequence.length += 1;
      } else {
      // if we are not in a sequence - create a new one
        result.push({startIndex: index, length: 1, startValue: el.value});
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Complex was a wrong term. A better term is nested. My intention was to write a readable code and not get better performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`For your specified array:`

```
var arr =[
    {type: 'A', value: 1}, {type: 'A', value: 2}, {type: 'B', text: 'b1'},
    {type: 'A', value: 11}, {type: 'A', value: 12}, {type: 'A', value: 13},
    {type: 'B', text: 'b2'}, {type: 'A', value: 10}, {type: 'B', text: 'b3'}
];

arr.reduce((result, current, index) => {
    if(current.type == 'A'){
        if(result.length == 0 || index - result[result.length - 1].length != result[result.length - 1]. startIndex){
            result.push({startIndex: index, startValue: current.value, length: 1})
        }
        else{
            result[result.length - 1].length++
        }
    }
    return result;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use declarative approach something like this instead imperative with forEach: You can use declarative approach something like this instead imperative with forEach:

```
  const a = [
  {type: 'A', value: 1}, {type: 'A', value: 2}, {type: 'B', text: 'b1'},
  {type: 'A', value: 11}, {type: 'A', value: 12}, {type: 'A', value: 13},
  {type: 'B', text: 'b2'}, {type: 'A', value: 10}, {type: 'B', text: 'b3'}
];

var filtered = a.map((v,i) => {
return v.type == 'A' ? {startIndex: i,startValue: v.value} : null
}).filter(x => x).reduce((acc,v) => {

if (acc.filter(x => x.startIndex + x.length  == v.startIndex).length > 0){
acc[acc.length-1].length ++;
} else {
v.length = 1;
acc.push(v);
}
return acc;
},[]);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there are already lots of good answers here, I thought I'd add one which addresses a more general case of segmenting a list. With this code, it's possible to specify a `segmenter` function, which compares two items and determines whether a new segment should be started.

Once you have these segments, getting to the final answer you require is quite simple.

```js
const data = [
  {type: 'A', value: 1}, {type: 'A', value: 2}, {type: 'B', text: 'b1'},
  {type: 'A', value: 11}, {type: 'A', value: 12}, {type: 'A', value: 13},
  {type: 'B', text: 'b2'}, {type: 'A', value: 10}, {type: 'B', text: 'b3'}
]

const segmentBy = segmenter => items => {
  const segmentReducer = (prev = [], curr) => {
    let lastSegment = [];
    let lastItem = null;
    
    try {
      lastSegment = prev[prev.length - 1];
      lastItem = lastSegment[lastSegment.length - 1];
    } catch (e) {
      return [...prev, [curr]];
    }
    const requiresNewSegment = segmenter(lastItem, curr);
    
    if (requiresNewSegment) {
      return [...prev, [curr]];
    }
    
    return [...prev.slice(0, prev.length - 1), [...lastSegment, curr]];
  };
  
  return items.reduce(segmentReducer, []);
};

const addIndex = a => a.map((x, i) => ({...x, index: i}))

const segmentByType = segmentBy((a, b) => a.type !== b.type);
const segments = segmentByType(addIndex(data));

const result = segments
  .map(segment => ({
    startIndex: segment[0].index,
    startValue: segment[0].value || null,
    length: segment.length
  }))
  .filter(x => x.startValue !== null)
  
console.dir(result);
```